# Page refresh in MVC is calling many methods in more than one controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a index page for which the the layout page is different and there is another index page in a different folder under the same project. Both these index pages have one and two partial views in each and also have their own controllers, one is home and the other testController.

My problem is when I hit f5 in the browser, it is calling the partial view method and index method for both the controllers home and the testcontroller and it is clearing off certain variables. My understanding is that it must call only the index method of the testcontroller and call the partial views which is in this page and controller. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide some code. Normally one controller's action processes one request and return one view (optionally with partial views in there). So what you described sounds strange, I want to see it :)

Comment: Partials are just a way of organizing the html. They have no context once the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem I had with both controller index methods being called. I was using the same layout page in both index pages. Point one of the index pages to the right layout page stopped calling the Home controllers index method.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you have a view that calls child actions. When you use `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction`, for the most part, it's as if you went to those actions directly via a URL. Everything that needs to happen to route to an action, run it, and return a rendered view has to happen for a child action, just as with a normal action.

Where your question gets confusing is in what you're expecting to happen when you refresh the page. Refreshing the page will replay the request to the server, which must then create and send the response just as it did for the original request. That means, your main action and any child actions will be hit again. I'm not sure why you would think something else should happen. Perhaps, you're wanting to only refresh a portion of the page? That's where AJAX comes in, but it won't help you with something like pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>. That will always cause the full page to be reloaded.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I am specifying RedirectToAction("Index", "Test"), so my thinking was it must call only the index method of 'Test' controller and not the 'home' controller. But it is calling both when i press F5. I have two index pages, two controllers and two layout pages.I would like automatic page refresh every few seconds which loads the partial views only on this page. user sets how many seconds they want the page refresh.

Comment: Yes, then it does sound like AJAX is what you're looking for. If you only want to update the content from the partial views, then you'll need to send a request to an action that returns `PartialView("_SomePartial")` via AJAX and then replace the innerHTML of some element in the DOM with that.